# Constructing a Facebook login app for android

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm using this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2?locale=en_GB) for facebook integration with android app.
That link says,

```
In main activity, make the activity subclass FragmentActivity instead of Activity:
```

Here is my code:

```
import com.facebook.AppEventsLogger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.
      AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      // Logs 'app deactivate' App Event.
      AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }
}
```

When I change `public class MainActivity extends Activity {` to `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {`, then I get the following errors:

```
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 11 Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 15 Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 21 Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 43 Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 48 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /Facebook/src/com/cheerz/facebook   line 14 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /Facebook/src/com/cheerz/facebook   line 21 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /Facebook/src/com/cheerz/facebook   line 31 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivityA.java  /Trial/src/com/cheerz/trial line 19 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivityA.java  /Trial/src/com/cheerz/trial line 21 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivityA.java  /Trial/src/com/cheerz/trial line 37 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivityB.java  /Trial/src/com/cheerz/trial line 16 Java Problem
The method activateApp(Context) in the type AppEventsLogger is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)  MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 24 Java Problem
The method deactivateApp(Context) in the type AppEventsLogger is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)    MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 51 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 30 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 14 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 28 Java Problem
The method onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) of type MainActivityA must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivityA.java  /Trial/src/com/cheerz/trial line 35 Java Problem
The method onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) of type MainActivityB must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivityB.java  /Trial/src/com/cheerz/trial line 13 Java Problem
The method onCreateView(String, Context, AttributeSet) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) MainActivityB.java  /Trial/src/com/cheerz/trial line 15 Java Problem
The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method   MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 35 Java Problem
The method onPause() of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 47 Java Problem
The method onResume() of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method    MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 20 Java Problem
The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type MainActivity   MainActivity.java   /Login/src/edu/cheerz/login line 16 Java Problem
```

How can I fix these errors? This is an experiment and would result in an awesome app ;)

Comment: The thing you cited said you need to subclass FragmentActivity instead of Activity, yet you are extending Activity. `public class MainActivity extends Activity` should read `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity` as per your question.

Comment: @dho: I didn't get you. How can I subclass `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`?

Comment: The extends keyword specifies the class you are subclassing. Simply use "extends FragmentActivity" instead of "extends Activity" when defining your MainActivity class

Comment: That is what I did. And it returned the errors mentioned in the question

Comment: The code in your question says "extends Activity"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I was getting confused between `android-support-v4` and `android-support-v7`. I was using `android-support-v7` and found that it doesn't support Fragment. So I used `v4` and it worked